# Why does the Archipack add-on add a black wall to my scene when trying to add a window?

Tags: add-on, archipack-add-on

I was using Blender 2.82a's Archipack add on, and whenever I try to add in a window to my scene in Blender, it comes up with a black wall looking thing, and a search bar, and I can't do anything to my scene once it is there. And I don't know what to type into the search bar. What am I supposed to do with it?

Comment: You need to generate the thumbnails first. This option is in the preferences of the add-on (*Edit > Preferences > Add-ons*, search for Archipack and open details section of the add-on).